# Is there any way to install Win32::OLE::Variant in ubuntu?

Tags: perl, abbyy

i tried to installing Win32::OLE::Variant in ubuntu  but it gave a bad operating system message and terminated ..

kindly help me to install this module in ubuntu

Thanks in advance

Selva Kumar

Comment: What are you trying to do? Win32::* modules are for Windows, so it doesn't make sense to install them on *nix.

Comment: [No](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Win32-OLE+0.1712)

Comment: i need to convert image to pdf with OCR so requires that Win32::OLE::Variant module to control many Win32 applications..@Thissuit

Comment: How did you install those applications on Ubuntu?

Comment: i installed that's not an issue now..

Comment: i already installed that package... that's not an issue now...i want to install  Win32::OLE ...suggest some ideas if  u have  @suitblack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) is a Microsoft technology that's only supported by Windows.

Comment: @ikegamo...Any other module is there instead of OLE for Linux ?

Comment: Win32 applications don't run on Linux, so such tools can't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This module **obviously** won't install on Ubuntu because it deals with Win32-exclusive API.

Comment: Any other module is there instead of OLE for Linux ?  @oleg